# Meaning of the prefix "verab"

Tags: prefix, semantics, morphology

What is the meaning of the prefix *verab* in the german word *Verabredung*? I assume it is a combination of *ver* and *ab*, but in this case, what does it express semantically?

Comment: I think this is something german.stackexchange could handle. It's a question of specific language semantics, not requiring fundamental linguistic semantics.I don't know a cognate outside of German that would make this a matter of comparative linguistics either.

Comment: @vectory Thank you for the tip!Much appreciated.

Comment: Synchronically, *Abrede* here is an agreement. *ver-* has various derivations, here denoting a state change. *ab-* is polysemous, pinpointing it is difficult. *Abmachung* is synonymous. *abgemache Sache*, ca. "collusion, conspiracy", is a hint at the sense "deviation", "outside of. ab- + ‎normal → ‎abnormal", from Latin, which is however *ab*sent from the colloquial meaning *Verabredung* "appointment, meeting"; Thus, cp. *vorab*, *voraus*. Also see *in Abrede stellen*; *Termin*; *bespoke, besprechen, bereden, versprechen*; and variously *abhängig*, *abfällig*, *abseits*, *ab-*, ...

Comment: Note that *ver-* could occasionally have a negative meaning: *acht-* "honour", *ver-acht-* "disdain* (to be confused with *ächt-* "disdain", no doubt). Maybe, though unlikely, it appeared first in "wir hatten eine Verabredung" (*we had a ... [but you didn't keep it]).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of a prefix in a german word](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49304/meaning-of-a-prefix-in-a-german-word)

Comment: Ver- is often used in verbs describing actions which yield some result (Examples: verarbeiten = to process, verstehen = to understand, versagen = to fail), so the ver- in verabreden refers to an agreement being reached.

Answer (score 4):

normally German *ab* is the equivalent of English *off* and expresses 'separation', but here it is indeed hard to understand how agreeing on an appointment is linked to the concept of separation.

Comment: I've looked at the word *Abrede* and it means *agreement*,as in something that is established by speaking out,or at least that's my guess. The question now is the meaning of *ver* though. What are your thoughts?

Comment: ver- is more a kind of grammatical tool, that expressing "achievement of the process". Cf ver-damm-t = damned

Answer (score 2):

Since *Verabredung* is a noun derived from the verb *verabreden*, let's look at verbs that begin with *verab-*. The first thing to note is that the group is very small. The pattern is not productive (in the linguistic sense; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics))). There are no new verbs being formed with *verab-*.

> verabreden, verabreichen, verabscheuen, verabschieden

Interestingly, the nouns *Abschied* and *Abscheu* (with the appropriate meaning) exist, so these verbs could be analyzed as adding *ver-* to a nominal base. But this doesn't work for *verabreichen*, as there is no potential base starting with *Abreich-*. It hardly works for *verabreden* either, as *Abrede* is quite restricted in the way it can be used (it mostly occurs as *in Abrede stellen*).

Either way, these verbs behave just like verbs with the prefix *ver-*:<sup>1</sup>

> *They can occur in fronted position:*
> Ich verGESse nie etwas. Wir verABreden uns zum Training.
>
> Zu *precedes the verb:*
> ohne es zu verGESsen, ohne sich zu verABschieden
>
> *There is no* ge- *in the past participle*:
> Hast du es verGESsen? Hast du dich verABschiedet?

Could they be analyzed as *ver-* plus a verbal base? They could, with an important caveat: The putative verbal bases must then be analyzed as *cranberry morphemes* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme)) that do not exist on their own. (Three of them – *abreichen*, *abscheuen*, *abschieden* – do not exist at all, and for *abreden*, the meaning doesn't fit very well.) This can be compared to a verb such as *verlieren*: *lieren* does not exist on its own, either.<sup>2</sup>

It follows from all of the above that the meaning of these verbs can't be derived from the meaning of the parts. In fact, it seems best to not see them as derived at all. Although *ver-* can be seen as indicating transitivity at least.

<sub>1 Should *verAB-* be analyzed as a prefix as the question suggests? I think not: verb prefixes don't bear stress, only verbal particles do. And those behave differently than prefixes: *Komm zuRÜCK!* *zuRÜCK**ge**kommen*, *zurRÜCK**zu**kommen*.</sub>

<sub>2 But note that deriving e.g. *verabreden* from *ver-* plus *abreden* is unusual, as *abreden* is made up of two words: a verbal particle and a verb.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Die Verabredung** is a noun made from the verb *verabreden*.

The verb *verabreden* means *to agree*. You can boil it down to

> reden – to talk
>
> abreden, absprechen – to bargain, to negotiate

So, *abreden* and *absprechen* is alternating in talk. You may draw a line to *abgeben* which means *to pass*, and *abfallen* which means *to come loose*. The prefix *ab-* often means something got loose.

> verabreden – to agree

So, *verabreden* is coming to a conclusion in *abreden*. Conclusion is a function *ver-* often carries.

---

In addition, there are multiple ways to make a noun from a verb:

> der/die/das Verabredende (from *Partizip I*) — the person who makes an agreement
>
> das Verabredete (from *Partizip II*) — the thing agreed upon
>
> das Verabreden (from *Infinitiv*) — the action of making an agreement
>
> die Verabredung (from *Infinitiv*) — the agreement

Comment: "Abreden" ohne "ver" habe ich noch nie gehört, mir ist nur "etwas in Abrede stellen" (=leugnen) bekannt. "Absprechen" hat gegenüber dem oben gesagten noch weitere Bedeutungen: positiv als "koordinieren" (wie sprechen unser Vorgehen aufeinander ab), negativ im Sinne von "jemandem eine bestimmte Kompetenz absprechen" (= behaupten, dass der betreffende diese Kompetenz nicht hat).